# Raphael JS : How can I change the path attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I built a line on the svg using raphael js library.
Here is my code:

```
var line = paper.path("M10,10L690,190");
line.attr({ 'arrow-end': 'classic-narrow-medium' });
line.attr({ 'stroke': '#000000', 'stroke-width':'5' });
```

And I checked the path on the chrome developer tool.
But the real path attribute is changed to

```
d="M10,10C10,10,609.759231954813,168.7597966939211,682.7523904336886,188.0815151147999"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: more details:  <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M10,10C10,10,609.759231954813,168.7597966939211,682.7523904336886,188.0815151147999" marker-end="url(#raphael-marker-endclassic32-obj1)" stroke-width="5" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real path is changed, because you are adding an arrow on the end which modifies it.

Comment: You're right. I parse the path with "Raphael.parsePathString" and it parses the path into two points.